# Maximizing $f$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, partial-derivative, maxima-minima, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> Find the domain and the maximum value that the function
>   $$f(x,y,z)=\frac{x+2y+3z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$$
>   may attain in its domain.

I have found the domain of the function to be $\mathbb{R^3\backslash\mathbf{0}}$. To maximize I differentiated in terms of $x,y,z$ having
$$f_x=\frac{-2 x y-3 x z+y^2+z^2}{\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{3/2}},\quad f_y=\frac{2 x^2-x y+z (2 z-3 y)}{\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{3/2}},\quad f_z=\frac{3 \left(x^2+y^2\right)-z (x+2 y)}{\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{3/2}}$$
But to solve the system $f_x=0,f_y=0$ and $f_z=0$ is rather hard. What are the plausible values of $x,y,z$?

Comment: The easy way is to use CS here. However if you want to try to solve it the calculus way notice that the function is homogenous (you can scale the parameters with the same number and retain the same function value) so you are free to assume $x=1$ in the system $f_x=f_y=f_z = 0$. This leaves you with a simpler system to solve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the vectors $\,\vec{u}=(x,y,z)\,$ and $\,\vec{v}=(1,2,3)$, then we can write
$$\frac{x+2y+3z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}=\frac{\vec{u}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\vec{v}}{\Vert\vec{u}\Vert}=\frac{\Vert\vec{u}\Vert\Vert\vec{v}\Vert\cos(\alpha)}{\Vert\vec{u}\Vert}=\Vert\vec{v}\Vert\cos(\alpha)=\sqrt{1^2+2^2+3^2}\cos(\alpha
)=\sqrt{14}\cos(\alpha)$$

When is the last expression maximized? When $\alpha=k\pi,\,k\in\mathbb{Z}$, thus the maximum value of $f$ is $\sqrt{14}$.

Comment: I think it should be $2k\pi$

Answer (score 4):

By C-S $$(x^2+y^2+z^2)(1^2+2^2+3^2)\geq(x+2y+3z)^2,$$
which gives
$$-\sqrt{14}\leq\frac{x+2y+3z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\leq\sqrt{14}.$$
The equality occurs for $(x,y,z)||(1,2,3),$ which gives that we got a maximal value and the minimal value.

Comment: What does C-S mean?

Comment: It's Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the line
$x = t, y = 2t, z = 3t$

Along this line.

$f(t,2t,3t) = \frac {14 t}{\sqrt{14 t^2}} = \sqrt {14}$

let's find some orthogonal vectors.

$\mathbf u = (1,2,3)\\
\mathbf v = (2,-1,0)\\
\mathbf w = (0,3,-2)$

Any point in $\mathbb R^3$ is some linear combination

$c_1\mathbf u + c_2\mathbf v+ c_3\mathbf w$

$f(c_1\mathbf u + c_2\mathbf v+ c_3\mathbf w) = \frac {14c_1}{\sqrt{14c_1^2 + 5c_2^2 + 13c_3^2}}\\
|f|\le \sqrt 14 \text{ sgn}(c_1)$